# How do I automate the conversion of urls into their titles/company names in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheets has a dropdown function (see screenshot) when I hover over a url that reliably returns the title that I'm after. However I can't figure out how to automate this over a long list of urls. Whatever the function is, it's not publicly available. The purpose is to convert URLs into company names so if any kind soul has alternative solutions I am open to them. [screenshot of url to title function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvNSx.png)

I have tried importxml e.g. =Hyperlink($I2, IMPORTXML($I2,"//title")) but the result more often than not delivers unwanted text such as a description. I am not a developer so I tried to workshop it with chatgpt in apps script but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom Function to extract title from URL.

use the [following steps listed on this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function) to make a custom function and replace the typed function with your custom function code. For your case copy paste the following Code as in the screenshot.

```
function TitleFromURL(input) {
  var regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?([^\.]+)/;
  var match = input.match(regex);
  return match ? match[1] : '';
}
```

[image: TitleFromURL custom function]

Then save and use your new function as any Google Function in the cell type `=TitleFromURL(cellNumber)`, you will get your URL titles as the results in the following spread sheet.

[Get Title from URL Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhTBq53QLPa26xFAh4LKGn2RFKDTo6d-iVTuuWDHJ-Tf0ROy0f1QU0TrbYKL96ZelO1-AP7FWjKlJD/pubhtml)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately sheets isn't recognising the function. The results you shared not quite what I was after anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lliam No problem, you're welcome. considering the sheets won't recognize the function because it's a custom function, you will have to type it when applying for the first cell,  (autocomplete may not work), then drag for the rest of the cell. Considering the function itself, it may not work for every url as some urls have multiple subdomians .e.g. (http://www.answers.yahoo.com, current implementation return "answers" not "yahoo", but that may be tweaked a little if the regex is modified to get the last domain name before the tlds.